# One value is assigned to all my lists components

Tags: python, list

In order to reduce the quantity of code (and also lazyness) I did this in python thinking that it would make me write less than [`[0,0],[0,0]....`]

```
a = [[0,0]]*10
```

However when I was assigning something like `a[0][:] = [1,2]`, then all of my values became into [1,2] (like `[[1,2]]*10`)

I have checked and if I do the whole [`[0,0],[0,0]....`] I could solve the problem, but that's not good. Could anyone help me?

Comment: `[[0,0] for _ in range(10)]` works. But this is a duplicate of many other questions

Answer (score -1):

I solved it with Numpy.

```
a = np.array([[0, 0]] * 10)
```

Comment: There's more to this question; the problem is that creating nested lists like this only copies a reference to the inner list, so if you mutate one element, you mutate all of them.